# "SSL network extender service is down" error in IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, ssl, internet-explorer-11, windows-10, checkpoint

Using CheckPoint I'm trying to use a VPN access from work to my clients site, which worked fine in Windows 7 and 8. But in Windows 10 I'm getting the error "ssl network extender service is down..."

I get the error message just at the beginning of the request, when CheckPoint is trying to connect.

Trying to run Internet Explorer emulated as an another browser has no effect.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I resolved this issue by running IE 11 as an Administrator.

Comment: This almost works. It has its kinks and kirks, (protocols that sometimes are invalid), but at least it is better than nothing

Comment: This worked for me, despite the fact that the Windows account I use on Windows 10 is a local administrator. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

I resolved this issue by manually downloading the Windows 7 version of SNX (SSL Network Extender). It can be [downloaded here](https://gz0ne.wordpress.com/2010/07/17/check-point-vpn-client-support-for-windows-64-bit/), or found by searching for "SNX R71 For Windows 7"

The version I got is the following:

```
> File Name:        Check_Point_SNX_R71HFA1_For_Windows_800005013.msi
> Product:          SSL Network Extender Version    R71 Minor Version   HFA 01
> OS:               Windows, Windows 7 Build Number 
> MD5:              381dd25826c43f97e3f36308368fa8e6 
> Size:             722.43 KB 
> Date Published:   12/31/2009
```

After download and install I was prompted about downloading a newer updated version, and asked abount installing some Java applets. Accepting everything made it possible for me to login via Internet Explorer 11 in Windows 10.

**UPDATE**

While it (somewhat) works to run IE 11 as administrator, I thought I wanted to tell what the real problem is:

It turns out that it often is the SSL VPN for the server that doesn't support Windows 10. I have heard that checkpoint offers an official patch for Windows 10, but it requires a firewall upgrade.

Full support should be on its way from Checkpoint, but I don't know when. Until then they offer a beta client that I havn't tested, but that I have heard should solve most of the problems.

Comment: Following your approach bu my Java8.45 is failing with an unpleasant "undefined" popup. Which version do you use? Thanks

Comment: I just tried redoing the approach again, and I couldn't make it work again :/ Dang it! I had hoped I had found a work-around. If you find anything @DiegoFerri I would be very interested in hearing about it :D

Comment: Worked like a charm on Win 10.!

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I did:

1. I removed all programs which are related with network extender in control panel.
2. Then I run IE as administrator and then tried to do VPN
3. After this attempt, explorer automatically installed ssl network extender, started its service and then accomplished to do VPN without problem.

Answer (score 0):

Usually running IE as administrator fixes the error, but sometimes only uninstalling the SSL extenders helps. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

All of these point runs:

- You have to run IE in administrator mode
- You can download client checkpoint Endpoint Security VPN

Regards
V.

Answer (score -2):

I can solve this issue

install Mozila> right clic> Compatibility> Select W7> Acept

For me it work

Regards